# SSH does not allow Public key login for users other than root

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, password

I have an Ubuntu 22.04.1 installation and am using pubkey + private key authentication to log into ssh.

So here are the steps I took

1. I first created a key pair on my mac.
2. I then went onto the server and edited `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to add a new port for the ssh login
3. Opened that port up in the firewall (UFW) and closed the default 22.
4. I did an `ssh-copy-id -i /path/to/public/key root@host` to copy the public key onto the server.
5. Then `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` again to disallow password authentication
6. Restarted sshd and tested the connection with root. The connection worked just fine.
7. I reenabled password authentication and tested ssh with one of my sudo users (not root) using user + password over the new port. The connection worked just fine.
8. I did an `ssh-copy-id -i /path/to/public/key user@host` to copy the public key onto the server in the .ssh/authorised_keys for that particular user. The procedure returned no errors and reported that one key was copied. I logged into the server and double-checked the authorised_keys file and the key was indeed there.
9. Then `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` again to disallow password authentication
10. Restarted sshd and tested the connection with user. **This is where I'm having a problem** The user cannot log in. When I try, I get an error: `Permission denied (publickey)`. When I reenable password authentication I can connect just fine but still without the keys. Just a standard username+password connection.

The key pair is tested since I use the exact same combination for the root user.
I want to disable Permitrootlogin but can't. Any ideas?

Edit: I followed the advice by @Jos and did a verbose sign-in using root ad one using user. Here are the 2 results. I've filtered out all sensitive info and keys, IPs etc and converted the results to screenshots:

[image: Root Debugging connection using verbose]

and the user (that fails to connect):

[image: User Debugging connection using verbose]

Edit:
@steeldriver suggested to do a namei to check if the authorized_keys files is overly permissive. Here is the output:

```
| => namei -l ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
f: /home/spitixorismesiti/.ssh/authorized_keys
drwxr-xr-x root             root             /
drwxr-xr-x root             root             home
drwxrwx--- spitixorismesiti spitixorismesiti spitixorismesiti
drwx------ spitixorismesiti spitixorismesiti .ssh
-rw------- spitixorismesiti spitixorismesiti authorized_keys
```

Comment: Try to login using `ssh` with a couple of `-v` switches so you get very verbose error messages, and a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: Having lots(even 3-4 keys is enough) of keys sometimes can cause issues, since it tries to use every single key individually. Try connecting while specifying which key to use with `-i /path/to/private/key`

Comment: I am using an ssh profile to log in and I have tried to use the `-i` parameter. I get the same results. I followed the advice by @Jos and did a verbose sign-in using `root` ad one using `user`. Here are the 2 results. I've filtered out all sensitive info and keys, IPs etc and converted the results to screenshots:
[root verbose](https://i.ibb.co/mN0YnPX/root-verbose.jpg)
and
[user verbose](https://i.ibb.co/1QyPx2j/user-verbose.jpg)

Comment: Is the user's home directory encrypted? if so, the default `~/.ssh/authorised_keys` won't be readable before it's decrypted and mounted (whereas `/root/.ssh/authorised_keys` likely will be)

Comment: Is there a way to check if it's encrypted? I'm not aware of such a thing.

edit: checked for .encryptfs files in /home and all related folders. Nope. Can't find any. It's probably not encrypted.

Comment: ... another possible gotcha is overly permissive access rights on the authorized_keys file or ~/.ssh directory tree - `namei -l ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` may be helpful

Comment: @escozul you can [edit] your question to include new information with proper formating

Comment: What kind of key pair did you create? Is it RSA?

Comment: it's ed25519. I don't think it's the compatibility that is the issue. The same key works for the root user. Also, looking at the verbose screens, it's obvious that ed25519 is supported. There is a different reason why it's not working for non-root users.